# Image hover and replace - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

Greetings I have been trying this for hours now and I am having trouble trying to figure it out. I am new to javascript and jquery. For example I have two images, a black and blue image. I have 4 black images that when hovered individually, changes the img src to blue, and goes back to black when hovered out. What I am trying to accomplish is that when you click the image/link, it will stay "blue". It will only change to "black" once you click on the other images.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<a id="catlnk1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadCat(1)"><img src="/images/blogpage/published.png" onmouseover="this.src='/images/blogpage/published-active.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/images/blogpage/published.png'" alt="Published" />
```

Script

```
function loadCat(num)
 { if (num == 1){
 $("#catlnk" + num).attr("src","/images/blogpage/published-active.png");
 } else if (num == 2){
 $("#catlnk" + num).attr("src","/images/blogpage/upcoming-active.png");
 } else if (num == 3){
 $("#catlnk" + num).attr("src","/images/blogpage/opening-active.png");
 } else if (num == 4){
 $("#catlnk" + num).attr("src","/images/blogpage/job-active.png");
 } 
}
```

Sorry if the code is messy, I'm new to this.

Comment: You're missing a word or two in the sentence, "What I am trying to accomplish is that when you click the or , ...". If you'll edit your question, we'll be in a better position to offer advice.

Comment: You'll likely get an answer more quickly if you include a working sample using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @JoeDeRose Sentence fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to bind events inline. Separate out your functionality from the design and bind the events using javascript or jQuery.

I am using `HTML-5` data-attributes called `data-image` that holds the image to be displayed.

So HTML will look like this.

**HTML**

```
<a id="catlnk1" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img data-image="published" src="/images/blogpage/published.png" alt="Published" />
</a>
<a id="catlnk2" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img data-image="upcoming" src="/images/blogpage/upcoming.png" alt="Upcoming" />
</a>
<a id="catlnk3" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img data-image="opening" src="/images/blogpage/opening.png" alt="Opening" />
</a>
<a id="catlnk4" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img data-image="job" src="/images/blogpage/job.png" alt="Job" />
</a>
```

**JS**

```
var url = "/images/blogpage/";
$('[id^=catlnk]').on({
    click: function (e) {
        var $currImg = $(this).find('img');
        $currImg.attr('src', function (_, src) {
            return url + $(this).data('image') + '-active.png';
        });

        // All images 
        $allImages = $('a > img');
        $allImages.not($currImg).each(function () {
            $(this).attr('src', function (_, src) {
                return url + $(this).data('image') + '.png';
            });
        });
        $currImg.addClass('clicked');
        $allImages.not($currImg).removeClass('clicked');
    },
    mouseover: function () {
        var $img = $(this).find('img');
        $img.attr('src', function (_, src) {
            return url + $(this).data('image') + '-active.png';
        });
        $img.addClass('active');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var $img = $(this).find('img');
        $img.attr('src', function (_, src) {
            return url + $(this).data('image') + '.png';
        });
        $img.removeClass('active');
    }

})
```

### **[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fGNua/1/)**

Comment: @Elmer.. Glad to have helped :)